# Go to declaration in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When we right click and click ***"Go to declaration"*** in Visual Studio, it navigates to that method.
What is the hotkey to **get back where we came from**?

Comment: Shortcut: 'Ctrl' and '-'. Microsoft have some nice posters with all the shortcuts: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will help you....! ;)

Answer (score 13):

Just another hint: <kbd>F12</kbd> goes to declaration, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> finds all references.

Comment: Resharper for 'finds all references' ;) is better.

Comment: Unfortunetaly, I can see no shortcut key for "Go to definition" in C#.

Comment: I have VS2008Team and VS2010Pro, both set to c# with its default shortcuts and they both behave the same: F12 does nothing. 'Go to definition' has no shortcut assigned. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mouse with a back button, that will take you back too.  You can then use the forward button to navigate forward again.

Comment: Is this new in VS2010 or something? I tried in my VS2008, and it didn't work. I double checked that the back/forward buttons actually works in my browser ,and they do, but not in VS for what you describe.

Comment: They've worked in every version of Visual Studio from 2005 for me, on multiple machines, locally and on RDP sessions, different OSs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Vs2022, Tools/Options/Keyboard
Select "`Edit.PreviousMethod`" or "`Edit.NextMethod`"

Shortcuts for selected command = `Ctrl + UpArrow` (Text Edit)

Idem for NextMethod