# Is there a <Jump To> button in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Is there a `Jump To` button in Visual Studio Code? Like the one in GitHub that lets you go to a specific function in the code. Any extension for this?

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826209/go-to-declaration-in-visual-studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to declaration in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826209/go-to-declaration-in-visual-studio)

Comment: None of them work in Javascript

Comment: @inostia that worked! Ctrl+shift+o on Windows 10.

Comment: great! i made it an answer. please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mac <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (on windows, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) will bring up a search bar that you can input your function/variable/method. VSCode will bring you to the definition.